# Why polar aprotic solvents don't surround negatively charged nucleophiles?

Tags: solvents, polarity, nucleophilicity

Protic solvents can form a tight shell around a nucleophile. But what's stopping any polar solvent from doing so? Shouldn't a polar solvent surround negatively charged $\ce{F-}$ with its partially positive side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a good explanation in [Oxford University presentations](http://staff.du.edu.eg/upfilestaff/447/courses/8447_1458459204__Nucleophilic2._.pdf).

It appears that partially positive side of aprotic solvents is hindered in the middle of the molecule. Only negative charge is on the surface. I've looked at DMSO, DMF, acetone, acetonitrile - all of them share this feature. So in case of a negatively charged ion - such solvents are not good at surrounding it.

It looks like elements that end up partially positive (except for $\ce{H}$) are those that can have 3+ bonds ($\ce{C}$, $\ce{S}$), so they are mostly surrounded by other atoms. It's only $\ce{H}$ who has 1 bond and therefore ends up at the surface of the molecule and can interact with negatively charged nucleophiles.